# Audit.Net not tracking new values

Tags: c#, audit.net

Trying to implement Audit.Net in a project using .Net Core and EF Core

Sample Context is defined as

```
  [AuditDbContext(Mode = AuditOptionMode.OptOut, IncludeEntityObjects = true, AuditEventType = "{database}_{context}")]
    public class MyContext : AuditDbContext
    {....
```

Main method has this start up code

```
using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                try
                {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<MyContext>();
                    DbInitializer.Initialize(context);

                    Audit.EntityFramework.Configuration.Setup()
                        .ForContext<MyContext>(config => config
                            .IncludeEntityObjects()
                            .AuditEventType("{context}:{database}"))
                        .UseOptOut()
                            .IgnoreAny(t => t.Name.EndsWith("History"));
                }....
```

Then the update code is

```
var personToUpdate = await _context.People.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ID == id);
using (var audit = AuditScope.Create("Person:Update", () => personToUpdate ))
{
              
                personToUpdate.FirstName = "audited";
                _context.SaveChanges();
              
}
```

After the save changes the auditscope.event.target.new is null

Not really sure what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create an `AuditScope`, the Audit.EntityFramework library will internally create the `AuditScope`. You just need to call the `SaveChanges()`

```cs
var personToUpdate = await _context.People.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ID == id);
personToUpdate.FirstName = "audited";
_context.SaveChanges();
```